# Call a function at a specific time without launching the app

Tags: c#, angular, ignite-ui-angular

I'm working on a .NET Core application using Angular and Ignite UI. I would like to ask if it is possible to run a function in the background without opening the webpage.

For example I want to run a function at midnight and export the current data from my grid, so that I can have the file in the morning.

Thanks

Comment: it is not possible unless you use a third party service.

Comment: It's better to obtain the data from the original data source that is populating your data grid.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - no. It's not possible to have a client-side background job when the client app is not running.

Longer answer - you probably need to rethink current approach to a feature you're building. Since you run on .NET Core you can use background jobs on the backend (plenty of job scheduling options like Hangfire, Quartz are available).
If you need some sort of "daily report" of what people typed in your data grid, and you store that info somewhere in db this would be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The daily report is just an example. For the daily report I have a function with an onClick-event. I have a similar function that I want to call on the background. :)

I suggested that it's not possible to call the function without running the application, but I decided to ask here.